# Why do we assume the photon has lost all its energy to the electron in the photo electric effect but not the Compton effect?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons

I was just revising the Compton effect for my exam and was wondering why in the case of the Compton effect we consider the photon as having collided with the electrons and only partially losing its energy and momentum. For the photoelectric effect we say the photon has been completely absorbed by the electron. In both cases light is incident on a material with bound electrons. Why the difference?

Comment: Note that in analyzing the photoelectric effect you worry about the voltage ($V_\text{max}$) current which cuts off all current. Have you asked what happens when a lower voltage is applied? Why is that?

Comment: Just two different types of electron-photon interactions. Like food types. You drink liquids and eat solids.

Comment: Just checking, so if i was doing a standard experiment to test the photo electric effect, you will always have some photons being scattered as opposed to absorbed. What factor decides between the two?

Comment: @dmckee A lower stopping potential means that the max KE transferred by the photons is enough for a fraction of the electrons to have enough energy to cross the gap between the anode and cathode?

Comment: Right: *a fraction*. There are actually two causes for this, one the angular dispersion of the ejected electrons (which isn't so interesting here), but also a energetic disperion (which is interesting here).

Comment: @dmckee Just to relate it back to my question, it was my understanding the energetic dispersion ( the range of energies an electron has) is due to the fact that not all the electrons are released from the surface of the metal. Is it also the case that in some situations the photon has not given up all its energy?

Comment: Vishal Yeah. It easy to get the impression that the reaction is $\gamma + A \to e + A^+$ (where $A$ is an atom), but there are two complications. First if the photon is energetic enough you can have $\gamma + A \to \gamma' + e + A^+$ (where the photon only gives up some of it's energy). Secondly (and perhaps more important) there are *conduction electrons* present and they should be understood as being bound by the bulk and not by individual atoms.

Comment: dmckee Ah I will look into that, thanks for the clarification.